# How to block API call if not from my website?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, web-frontend, api-key

I have an application built around AWS:

- a lambda function
- an API gateway calling the lambda, must be called with an API key
- an S3 bucket as static website, that calls the API gateway

How can I secure the calls to the API gateway so that it cannot be called from anywhere but my S3 bucket ?

Some solutions have already come in my mind like:

- proxy : helps hiding the API key, but anyone accessing the proxy can call the API, right ?
- IP whitelisting : I can't know the IP range the bucket is using, so I can't do that

Thanks

Comment: Just a note, if you present a static website. And a call is made to your lambda. Who is making the call ? It's the user's WebBrowser. So IP filtering would not work. Are there any CORS rule settings in lambda ? (or the proxy component of AWS). Because that might help, especially if you use HSTS on top of HTTPS

Comment: To enable CORS on AWS lambda : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

Comment: I'd say that none of your proposed solutions actually work because the request won't actually come from your s3 bucket, but actually from the users browser. Assuming you're ok with having your users register and allowing only registered user make the calls to the API you could do something like https://www.experoinc.com/post/serverless-authentication. Otherwise you could, with a lambda@edge, look into the header of your req and see where it's coming from, keep in mind that this won't stop me from using Postman and writing whatever I want in that header.

Comment: You're right, API is called from browser. I think CORS will not block API calls from a tool like `curl` for example, right ? In my app, the page is public so I cannot use authentication unfortunately.

Comment: @dooxe you are correct, curl will still work. I suggest going with CORS and rate limiting, if there's something better than that I don't know it.

Comment: Yes, it seems to a difficult problem actually, I've been stuck for a while. Thanks a lot for your answers

Comment: Nope, I finally used a lambda to implement an htaccess-lie HTTP auth to "protect" the web page.